# No write access to clients git repository

Tags: git, repository, git-push

I've got to make some changes to a clients website but when I try to `push` to remote (on codebasehq.com), I'm told I don't have write access to the repository. In case it was an issue with the SSH key I set up, I removed it (from codebasehq.com) in this scenario and then tried to `push` again and this time was told 'permission denied (publickey)' so this confirms the key was okay.

I'm unsure what I am supposed to do to give myself write access to the repo? I've tried searching but not found anything I particularly grasp other than initialising with `git init --shared` (already done).

Does my client have to provide the write access to the remote repo or is it something I can get around myself, and if so, how?

Comment: Can you please provide error message copy?

Comment: I have not worked with CodebaseHQ.com, but with my experience with GitLab and GitHub, I am suspecting that you might have not been given write permission to the repository in question.

Can you confirm that you are indeed given the said permission?

Comment: @shirakia the error is "Error: You do not have write access to this repository.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
"

Comment: @budhajeewa no idea - they've requested I make the changes so would have thought they would have provided write access (however that is done) - I shall check with them though.

Comment: thanks. it looks git error message. Codebase seems to have archive function. https://www.codebasehq.com/features/project-management Is it an old project? they might archive it

Comment: @shirakia nope, the project isn't archived - it is in 'active' state.

Comment: @zigojacko: Please check with your client and let us know.

Comment: @budhajeewa - yes, it is now sorted thanks and was purely just down to the client not providing the necessary write access in codebasehq.com.

Comment: @zigojacko: I am happy that you were able to sort it out. I added the worked "solution" as an answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27562324/445438), please accept it so it might serve people who face the same problem in the future.

Comment: I had already [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27550789/898933) the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually resolved by the client needing to actually provide us with write access to the repository (which I presume is set up for users within codebasehq.com).

Answer (score 0):

Your client might not have provided write permissions to your user account. Please inquire them.